# JSP variable that is not a variable

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I had some problem with the variable COMICI, as I need it in two different state (connected to the variable username) I put it in and outside of `if`, but when I call it eclipse told me that it cannot be considerate a variable.
Any idea about why?

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");

if(username!= null){
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = (Connection)    
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login",  "root", "");
    Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1;
    st1.executeQuery("SELECT 'COMICI' from categorie WHERE UTENTE_ID = '"+username+"' ");       
    PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement)con.prepareStatement("SELECT COMICI from categorie WHERE UTENTE_ID = '"+username+"' ");
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    String COMICI=rs.getString("COMICI");
} else {
    String COMICI=("null");
}

%>

<%
   if(username!=null)     {
%>
<%      
 //select * from categorie where UTENTE_ID='
        out.print("Hello, "+username+" Welcome to Profile");
        out.print("Hello,"+ COMICI +"  Welcome to Profile");
   }
%>
```

Comment: It's out of scope. You need to declare it (and initialize it) before the `if`. And **please** format your code! This is painful to read and full of syntax errors.

Comment: I see, I'll be more careful in the future. Thank very much for help.

Comment: Now that you've added the `else` block, you don't need to initialize it when you declare it, because it's initialized by all paths.

Comment: Yep, I tried this solution, but now at the line  
code`  
out.print("Hello,"+ COMICI +"  Welcome to Profile")
Eclipse give me this error message: 
COMICI cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You tried which solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have many problems in your code :

**First**
You have to declare your variables outside your if or else block :

```
String COMICI = "";
if (username != null) {
   COMICI = rs.getString("COMICI");
   ...
}else{
   COMICI = null;
}
```

**Second**
To inisialize your variable you don't need to make parentheses:

```
COMICI = ("null");
```

Instead use :

```
COMICI = "null";
```

**Third**
Instead of using Statement this can cause syntax error or SQL Injection, you have to use PreparedStatement its more secure and more helpful.

**Fourth**
To get result from your ResultSet you have to use :

```
if(rs.next()){
   COMICI = rs.getString("COMICI");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works,try it

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
string COMICI=null;

    if(username!= null){
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection)    
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login",  "root", "");
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1;
        st1.executeQuery("SELECT 'COMICI' from categorie WHERE UTENTE_ID = '"+username+"' ");       
        PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement)con.prepareStatement("SELECT COMICI from categorie WHERE UTENTE_ID = '"+username+"' ");
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

       if( rs.next())
      {
        COMICI=rs.getString("COMICI");
    } else {
         COMICI="null";


    }

    %>

    <%
       if(username!=null)     {
    %>
    <%      
     //select * from categorie where UTENTE_ID='
            out.print("Hello, "+username+" Welcome to Profile");
            out.print("Hello,"+ COMICI +"  Welcome to Profile");
       }
    %>
```